# How to control the type being rendered by react-Lottie (svg/video tag)

Tags: reactjs, lottie

I rendered two react-Lottie animations my app. One shows in the dom as `video` tag. and one shows as `SVG` tag. How do I control the type being rendered?

```
  const MyOptions: Options = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice',
    },
  };
  return (
    <Lottie options={MyOptions}/>
  );
```

Comment: Could you post a sample code sandbox of this problem? It's easier to debug the same.

Comment: Hey, I added the code.

Comment: Thank you, while this code would make sense with the configuration, can you reproduce the same via https;//codesandbox.io/ or similar online tool and show the result? It's easier to know what kind of error you are seeing or issues are seen visually.

Comment: I have no error, I just get sometimes SVG and sometimes Video, my question is: how to control that?

Comment: Sure, can you reproduce that via https://codesandbox.io/ ? It's easier to debug and provide more information.

Comment: If I understood correctly, based on a type you want to render a specific HTML. You can try go through this code snippet.                                                                   
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const firstHtmlIndicator = true;
  const FirstHtml = () => {return (<p>First Html</p>) };
   const SecondHtml = () => {return (<p>second Html</p>) };
  
  return (<>{firstHtmlIndicator ? <FirstHtml /> : <SecondHtml />}</>);
}

Comment: Whatttt how does this answer my question????